# Mysql database connection to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect mysql database to a php program. I used following program to establish connection. But it is not giving any error even I make any mistake with the code.

```
<?php
// creating database connection

$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "1234";
$dbname = "my_new";
//connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

//testing connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die ("database connection failed :".
    mysqli_connect_error() .
    "(".mysqli_connect_errno().")"
    );
    }

?>
```

Comment: surround your connection with `try-catch` OR check error in `error_log` file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was a problem with php-mysql connector. But I am going to use try-catch block, its a good programming practice for database connections. Thanks again for suggesting it.

Comment: @Sachith please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my computer, your code is work well. And I find that mysql_connect will not throw exception.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: It was a problem with php_mysql package. Yes this code worked fine after installing php_mysql pack again.